# calculus: when can the infinitesimal be cancelled and when not?

Tags: calculus

Following Professor Leonard's lectures, we come to one derivative calculation ('h' being the infinitesimal and 'x' being the normal variable) where he dutifully gets to the point where 'h' over 'h' is canceled out and then we are left with this:

$\dfrac{1} {\sqrt{x+h} + \sqrt{x} }$

... and he then just tosses the remaining 'h' and the equation reduces to:

$\dfrac{1} {2\sqrt{x}}$

Now, there have been terms with 'h' in the numerator that he's thrown away before.  It seems that once 'h' in the denominator is removed algebraically, you can throw away any numerator 'h' freely. But the above 'h' is in the denominator, and the 'sqrt(x)', too, can go to zero, so I'm not clear how the above 'h' can be thrown away. It seems we don't need to specify a limit for 'x', but we do for 'h'.  Is it that a multiplication by 'h' in the denominator is forbidden, but a summed 'h' can be thrown away?  That's the feeling I get but I'm not sure.

Sorry for the simple questions but I have no one else to ask.  I appreciate the trouble taken by folks who are light-year beyond me.

Comment: It is better to think about $h$ as a real variable in the context of limit definitions (like for derivatives), and not as "an infinitesimal".  The notation in calculus retains infinitesimals such as $\mathrm d x,\mathrm d y$ because of their intuitive operation, but the limit definition of derivatives  (or integrals) introduces rigor (and we can reason about $h\to 0$ as one might about any nonzero number).

Comment: "and the 'sqrt(x)', too, can go to zero" -- no, it cannot. This calculation is done in the context of a limit as $h$ goes to zero, which means that everything that is _not_ $h$ or a function of $h$ (including $x$) remains exactly the same as it was before we started fiddling with $h.$

Comment: I know, but it is possible for 'x' to equal zero as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $h\to 0$, $x$ cannot be $0$, or else there will be division by zero. A basic technique for evaluating limits is direct substitution, which is why the professor was able to "throw away" the $h$ like you said. Direct substitution simply means substituting the values that variables are approaching for those variables (e.g. if $h\to 0$, then the value $0$ can be substituted for $h$). Also, you're only learning single variable calculus, so yes, you only need to specify the limit for one variable. Multiplication by $h$ in the denominator is forbidden because division by $0$ is forbidden and $h\to 0$. The reason why the professor was able to cancel the $h's$ in the numerator and denominator is because he was using another limit evaluation technique called factoring.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So the denominator 'h' can be removed because it's part of a sum?

Comment: Yeah, basically. If you want to know more about evaluating limits, go to http://www.milefoot.com/math/calculus/limits/LimitStrategies11.htm. The same principles can be applied to your case.

Comment: I'll check that out, thanks.  Prof. L has been quite rigorous in his lectures, but the above was glossed over a bit too quickly IMHO.

Comment: I think I get it: '1/(h*????)' must always produce 1/0 no matter what '????' may be so in that case 'h' must be factored out, or gotten rid of algebraically.  But: '1/(h+????)' does not break the denominator entirely, we have only the singularity when '????' happens to equal zero, so the 'h' can simply be ignored, yes?  It changes nothing so it is nothing.

Comment: Thanks @ford.  You know, sometimes a simple answer really will do nicely for the short term :-)  Deeper things will follow, no doubt.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function $y=\sqrt x$. By definition, the derivative of $y$ at $x=x_0> 0$:
$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x_0+h}-\sqrt{x_0}}{h}=\\
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x_0+h}-\sqrt{x_0}}{h}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{x_0+h}+\sqrt{x_0}}{\sqrt{x_0+h}+\sqrt{x_0}}=\\
\lim_{h\to 0} \require{cancel}\frac{\cancel h}{\cancel h(\sqrt{x_0+h}+\sqrt{x_0})}=\\
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x_0+h}+\sqrt{x_0}}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x_0}},$$
because the limit is with respect to $h$ and $x_0$ is a constant term.

Answer (score 0):

You must have some calculation that got to $$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac 1{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt x}$$ by canceling $h$ from the numerator and denominator.  Once you are to this point, you should have theorems that say the limit of a sum is the sum of the limits and the limit of a fraction is the fraction of the limits as long as the denominator is not zero.  You can then make this 
$$\frac 1{\lim_{h \to 0}\sqrt{x+h}+\lim_{h \to 0}\sqrt x}$$
and we know both limits are $\sqrt x$

Comment: But the second term is no issue.  Can you use the same logic to break up the 'x+h'?  I belabor this because up to a certain point you absolutely can't throw any 'h' away, then after that point you can throw them all away.  It seems that the point where 'h/h' is canceled top and bottom is the magic moment. It seems to always happen and to always be the moment, but Prof. L is not absolutely clear on the point.

Comment: You are not throwing $h$ away, you are asserting that the limit of $\sqrt {x+h}$ is $\sqrt x$.  It is true that once you eliminate the indeterminate, it looks like throwing $h$ away because you get the result as if you just set $h=0$.  This is based on the theorems I mentioned.